# How to get the name of the day in PHP using date?

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the day's name in the row of numbers converted to date? I have the Code :

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-01');
$Month = date('m', strtotime($date1));
$Year = date('Y', strtotime($date1));
$Maximum_Date = date('t', strtotime($date1));

for($Date = 1; $Date <= $Maximum_Date; $Date++){
  $DataDate = $Date . ' ' . $Month . ' ' . $Year . '<BR>';
  echo $DataDate;
}
```

**Result:**

```
1 04 2019
2 04 2019
3 04 2019
etc...
```

What I want is to change it to display the name of the day on that date

For Example Date in April :

```
Monday, 1 04 2019
Tuesday, 2 04 2019
Wednesday, 3 04 2019
etc...
```

**[UPDATE] April 15, 2019**
Refer to comments, I see documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and apply with `mktime();`

So I Update The Code :

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-01');
$Month = date('m', strtotime($date1));
$Year = date('Y', strtotime($date1));
$Maximum_Date = date('t', strtotime($date1));

for($Date = 1; $Date <= $Maximum_Date; $Date++){
  echo date("l, d m Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $Month, $Date, $Year)) . '<br>';
}
```

And get the result :

```
Monday, 1 04 2019
Tuesday, 2 04 2019
Wednesday, 3 04 2019
etc...
```

Comment: did you check here at all? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this a lot without converting back and forth between `date` and `strtotime`:

```
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('n');
$lastDay = date('t');

foreach (range(1, $lastDay) as $day) {
    echo date('D, j m Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year)), '<br>';
}
```

See http://php.net/mktime.

Omitting implicit default values and condensing it a bit, you can in fact boil it down to:

```
foreach (range(1, date('t')) as $day) {
    echo date('D, j m Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), $day)), '<br>';
}
```

```
Mon, 1 04 2019
Tue, 2 04 2019
Wed, 3 04 2019
...
Tue, 30 04 2019
```

Note that this code has a minuscule potential to break, should you execute it right at the second in which one month rolls over to the next, and the `date('n')` and `date('t')` functions happen to be called "in different months". To avoid that possibility entirely, make this operation atomic:

```
list($year, $month, $lastDay) = explode(' ', date('Y n t'));

foreach (range(1, $lastDay) as $day) {
    echo date('D, j m Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year)), '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will print out what you need..

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-01');
$Maximum_Date = date('t', strtotime($date1));

for($Date = 1; $Date <= $Maximum_Date; $Date++)
{
    $thatDay = date('Y-m-'.$Date);
    $day = date('l, j', strtotime($thatDay));
    $Month = date('m', strtotime($thatDay));
    $Year = date('Y', strtotime($thatDay));

    echo $day . ' ' . $Month . ' ' . $Year . '<BR>';
}
```

**Output:**

```
Monday, 1 04 2019
Tuesday, 2 04 2019
Wednesday, 3 04 2019
Thursday, 4 04 2019
Friday, 5 04 2019
...
...
```

if you change this line

```
$day = date('l, j', strtotime($thatDay));
```

TO

```
$day = date('l, jS', strtotime($thatDay));
```

The output will be: **Monday, 1st 04 2019**

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-01');
$Month = date('m', strtotime($date1));
$Year = date('Y', strtotime($date1));
$Maximum_Date = date('t', strtotime($date1));

for($Date = 1; $Date <= $Maximum_Date; $Date++){
  $DataDate = date("D-m-Y",strtotime($Year."-".$Month."-".$Date));
  echo $DataDate. '<br>';;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try like below.

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-01');
$Month = date('m', strtotime($date1));
$Year = date('Y', strtotime($date1));
$Maximum_Date = date('t', strtotime($date1));

$StartDate=$date1;
$EndDate=($Year."-".$Month."-".$Maximum_Date);
$EndDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($EndDate));

while(strtotime($EndDate)>=strtotime($StartDate))
{
    echo date('l, d-m-Y',strtotime($StartDate))."<br/>";
    $StartDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($StartDate . ' +1 day'));
}
```

After execute you will get result like below.

```
Monday, 01-04-2019
Tuesday, 02-04-2019
Wednesday, 03-04-2019
...................
...................
...................
...................
Saturday, 27-04-2019
Sunday, 28-04-2019
Monday, 29-04-2019
Tuesday, 30-04-2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your loop:

```
    echo (new DateTime($Date. '-'. $Month .'-'. $Year))->format('l');
```

It creates a new DateTime object with your data & echo's the day in the format that you requested.